# Post an image to facebook failed in android using facebook SDk 4.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am working on an android app and want to share an image to facebook from my app but without showing dialog,I have tried as below,But its not working .Can anybody help me for this?

**code**

```
public void postFb(){ String path = "me/feed";
        AccessToken at = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Const.bmp_post.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        parameters.putByteArray("picture", byteArray);
        HttpMethod method = HttpMethod.POST;
        GraphRequest.Callback cb = new GraphRequest.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                Log.d("=======graph response=======" , graphResponse.toString());
                //check graphResponse for success or failure
                if(graphResponse.getError()==null){

                    Toast.makeText(NewPostActivity.this, "Successfully posted to Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(NewPostActivity.this, "Facebook: There was an error, Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        };

        GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(at,path,parameters,method,cb);
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: @mdDroid - Please see this error.`{Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#100) picture is not properly formatted}}`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `"/me/feed"` to  `"me/photos"`

Comment: nai bhai..wait let me se

Comment: i am getting this eror now :9`{Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, errorType: GraphMethodException, errorMessage: Unsupported post request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api}}`

Comment: have you granted publish_stream  permission

Comment: Where is it? how to do that bro?